# Re-configuring allauth to fit custom specifications

Tags: python, django

I have a set of expectations I'm trying to achieve. I want a sign up, login, and forget password page. I also want to have social sign in using Twitter, Facebook, or Google. Another thing I want is to send a confirmation email to the user validating their account.

I know I can do this with Django allauth, but allauth comes with extra features that I don't need. For example, I don't need the password reset and change email pages. I want to remove these pages and their corresponding functionality, but I'm afraid I might break the code if I do this.

I was thinking about two solutions. One solution would be to go through the allauth templates and change some of the code to fit my specifications, but I feel like it would be very tedious because a lot of things might break if I remove some funcionality.

The second solution I was thinking of doing was building on top of auth and using a custom User model and building custom login, sign up, and reset pages. Adding the required functionality and everything. I could also build the models to provide social login by copying allauth's templates. I am just debating on what would be the best possible choice to do this. I would be happy if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core and other modules - former Python Social Auth is deprecated now in favor of this library.

Comment: @dmitryro Yes, but should I build all this myself or use allauth instead. What is preferred based on my specifications?

Comment: This library will provide you with most comprehensive support for all social backends you may need - Twitter, LinkedIn, Facebook, Google. Your task is still to set up properly apps on those social networks you want to use, get the links and set them up with your templates. Configure values in settings.py as described in the specs. No need to code other than configuring it properly - if you need extended pipeline you may need to add some custom code, like reading avatars, friends, depends.

Comment: @dmitryro Yes, but do you think that using this module is better than using allauth? Instead of using allauth and re-configuring it to my expectations?

Comment: Activation logic is not part of it - it's a custom feature you're implementing yourself - registration_api module with Django Rest Framework has similar logic for providing activation tokens https://github.com/alej0varas/django-registration-rest-framework all you need is to generate this token and send it via email.

Comment: Have implemented it myself - pretty straightforward. You can give a try to both if you want, but process is similar, it's more about configuring things properly.

Comment: @dmitryro What was the reason for you to not use allauth though?

Comment: For me the use of social auth was - the number of different backends provided (I needed Linked In, Twitter, Facebook and G+ working with no bidding - just working), the pipeline allowing me to read custom avatars and custom metadata from those APIs without fancy use of third party modules, and the deprecation/Python 3 timing and features, maintenance activity. Those two libraries are pretty much nose to nose, but as I needed the most in terms of pipeline, I used Python Social Auth.

Comment: @dmitryro How'd you do Twitter sign up with that module? Since Twitter doesn't provide you email addresses?

Comment: Twitter provides private key and public key, which you configure in your settings.py, and then you use `SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET` from the app in Twitter, use `social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth` as backend - I just needed to have the Oauth authentication working properly - in case of Twitter I did not read the email, but FB and G+ provide emails and avatars (Twitter does two, along with some other metadata).

Comment: The activation step consisted of `from registration_api import utils` from the third party module I mentioned, generating token as `activation_key = utils.create_activation_key(user)` and `link = settings.BASE_URL+'/activate/{}'.format(activation_key)` then sending this link in the email body.

Comment: @dmitryro Did you build upon auth or did you actually make the users model yourself?

Comment: I used the standard Django user `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`  and for the missing  fields - a custom Profile model which had user as `user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)` field - this is a preferred approach to extend User in Django (rather than subclassing or using inheritance).  The profile was needed for avatars, types of users that are out of User scope, but implementing it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: And then a number of function views to handle all those use cases - send activation, activate, signin, verify details - the client side of it used Vue as presentation layer, talking to Django views.

Comment: @dmitryro Sorry to keep on asking you questions, but what is the purpose of you doing a OneToOneField? What does this do?

Comment: The purpose is to not have to patch the User object, not to deal with Inheritance (in this case things get far form being consistent, if not 1-1) and have a structure that lives as long as User lives, gets removed when User gets removed, and gets updated when User gets updated - id and user id are always same, so they live same life, but the Profile object in this case has all the properties that User misses.

Comment: @dmitryro Oh so for example if we were at profiles/charlie we could take the username 'charlie' and query profiles and we'd get both the User model and the profile model in one query?

Comment: Yes, and then if you have `user = User.objects.get(id=1)`, then `profile` is just `user.profile`, say, avatar_path if you declare, for example, is `user.profile.avatar_path` and the opposite, if you have `p = Profile.objects.get(id=1)` then the user is `p.user`, first name is `p.user.first_name` and so on. they are mutually interchangeable when called.

Comment: @dmitryro Wow, I didn't know that. Thank you for that extra insight!

Comment: @dmitryro For the module that you sent me, is there any documentation or tutorials on how to use it. I know the github page has some documentation, but it seems like they're explaining python social auth